# Android phone usb

Tags: android, usb

I want to make a remote control for my tv using my android phone. I plan to connect my external infrared device to the phone via usb. An application on the phone should do the processing and send out commands to the infrared device via usb. Is it possible to explicitly access the phone's usb interface from the application to send/receive data? The data will just  be short binary strings. In one instance, the phone should be the host and in the other instance, the phone should be a client.

Answer (score 4):

For this to be possible, I believe you will need a [USB host drive](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android%20usb%20host)r for your phone.  While these drivers are available for some devices (see link), you'll need to have root access to install them, and it won't be easy.  For instance, [here's a description](http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/) of how to install a USB host driver for the Nexus One.

Given how few devices support USB host, there seems to be very little documentation one how one would actually go about accessing a specific USB device.  The second link above, to the Nexus One driver, provides some sparse details.  Beyond that I can only assume that you'd need to write your own driver for the specific device, which would probably be similar to standard [Linux USB driver development](http://www.lrr.in.tum.de/Par/arch/usb/usbdoc/).  [This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=694427) (started by the author of the N1 USB host driver) is probably the best source of information you'll find.

Unfortunately the short answer is that what you want to do will be very difficult, and you certainly won't be able to distribute your work easily if you do manage it.  Good luck!